# Android DialogFragment and EditText not restoring state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Please help me. I don't know why, but after screen rotation EditText is empty. I use setRetainInstance(true), but it doesn't help for me. Please tell me what is the right way to save dialog's state and EditText's state with selection and text

My code:

```
public class InputTextDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    static final String DIALOG_TAG = "InputTextDialog";

    static EditText input;
    String initialText;
    InputTextDialogListener inputTextDialogListener = null;

    public interface InputTextDialogListener {
        void onChangeText(String text);
    }

    public void setInputTextDialogListener(InputTextDialogListener listener) {
        inputTextDialogListener = listener;
    }

    public void setInitialText(String text) {
        initialText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
      if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
        getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
      super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        input = new EditText(getActivity());
        input.setHint("Enter your text");

        if (initialText != null) {
            input.setText(initialText);
        } else {
            input.setText("");
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Enter your text").setPositiveButton("Apply", this)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", this).setView(input);
        return adb.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE && inputTextDialogListener != null) {
            inputTextDialogListener.onChangeText(input.getText().toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Show dialog in activity:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                InputTextDialog inputDialog = new InputTextDialog();
                inputDialog.setInitialText(initialText);
                inputDialog.setInputTextDialogListener(new InputTextDialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onChangeText(String text) {
                        resultText = text;
                    }
                });

                inputDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), InputTextDialog.DIALOG_TAG);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I solved this by:

```
package com.xfakehopex.lovelywidget.Dialogs;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class InputTextDialog extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {

    public static final String DIALOG_TAG = "InputTextDialog";

    private static final String DIALOG_TITLE_BUNDLE= "dialogTitle";
    private static final String DIALOG_TEXT_BUNDLE= "dialogText";
    private static final String DIALOG_TEXT_SELECTION_START_BUNDLE = "dialogTextSelectionStart";
    private static final String DIALOG_TEXT_SELECTION_END_BUNDLE = "dialogTextSelectionEnd";

    private EditText input;
    private String initialText;
    private String title;
    InputTextDialogListener inputTextDialogListener = null;

    public interface InputTextDialogListener {
        void onChangeText(String text);
    }

    public void setInputTextDialogListener(InputTextDialogListener listener) {
        inputTextDialogListener = listener;
    }

    public void setInitialText(String text) {
        initialText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        input = new EditText(getActivity());
        input.setHint("Введите текст");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String text = savedInstanceState.getString(DIALOG_TEXT_BUNDLE);
            title = savedInstanceState.getString(DIALOG_TITLE_BUNDLE);
            int selectionStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(DIALOG_TEXT_SELECTION_START_BUNDLE);
            int selectionEnd = savedInstanceState.getInt(DIALOG_TEXT_SELECTION_END_BUNDLE);

            input.setText(text);
            input.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        }
        else
        {
            if (initialText != null) {
                input.setText(initialText);
            } else {
                input.setText("");
            }
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle(title).setPositiveButton("Apply", this)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", this).setView(input);
        return adb.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saved) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(saved);

        saved.putString(DIALOG_TEXT_BUNDLE, input.getText().toString());
        saved.putString(DIALOG_TITLE_BUNDLE, title);
        saved.putInt(DIALOG_TEXT_SELECTION_START_BUNDLE, input.getSelectionStart());
        saved.putInt(DIALOG_TEXT_SELECTION_END_BUNDLE, input.getSelectionEnd());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        if (which == Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE && inputTextDialogListener != null) {
            inputTextDialogListener.onChangeText(input.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```